# sObject array parameter in Lightning causes Internal Salesforce.com Error in Apex controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Why do I get an **Internal Salesforce.com Error** when trying to pass an array of sObject values to an Apex controller action method?

I've posted a simple gist to demonstrate this problem to GitHub: https://gist.github.com/martyychang/76867c92f19808b6a7b7

The way to reproduce the problem is:

1. Enable debug logging for yourself
2. Launch oneLead.app (after you've created everything in the gist and tweaked the namespace references)
3. Submitting a single lead works fine using the **first Submit button**, as expected
4. Adding multiple leads and then submitting all of them using the ***bottom* Submit button** causes the Internal Salesforce.com Error

Is there something simple that I'm doing wrong? All I want to do is pass a List object as a parameter to my Apex controller from my Lightning component.

Comment: I observed the same with a `List<String>` when doing [this code](https://gist.github.com/peterknolle/ef17727d994332a8ef6b) and had to workaround it by converting the List to a String.

Comment: It's a year after the last post and I still have the same problem. I got around it by making my list a comma delimited String and then tokenizing that on the server side. Any word on whether or not this will be fixed soon?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is deep inside of the transport/marshalling interface layer between Lightning Components and Apex and will need to be fixed by my team.

For now I have developed a generic workaround using a small amount of Apex.

```
public class OneLeadController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id createLead(Lead newLead) {
        insert newLead;
        return newLead.Id;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Id> createLeads(String newLeads) {
        List<SObject> newSObjectsList = convertJSONToListOfSObject(newLeads);

        insert newSObjectsList;

        List<Id> newIds = new List<Id>();
        for (SObject o : newSObjectsList) {
            newIds.add(o.Id);
        }

        return newIds;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Lead newLead() {
        return (Lead)Lead.sObjectType.newSObject(null, true);
    }

    private static List<SObject> convertJSONToListOfSObject(String json) {
        Object[] values = (Object[])System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(json);

        List<SObject> newSObjectsList = new List<SObject>();
        for (Object v : values) {
            Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)v;

            Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get((String)m.get('sobjectType'));

            SObject o = targetType.newSObject();

            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = targetType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            for (String fieldName : m.keySet()) {
                // Filter out any psuedo fields such as LastNameLocal
                Schema.SObjectField fi = fields.get(fieldName);
                if (fi != null) {
                    if (fi.getDescribe().isCreateable() && fi.getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
                        o.put(fieldName, m.get(fieldName)); 
                    }
                }
            }

            newSObjectsList.add(o);
        }

        return newSObjectsList;
    }
}
```

and a small corresponding change to the client side controller (oneLeadController.js) calling this:

```
({
    save : function(component, event, helper) {
        var self = this;

        var createLeads = component.get("c.createLeads");
        createLeads.setParams({
            "newLeads": $A.util.json.encode(component.get("v.leads"))
        });

        createLeads.setCallback(self, function(a) {
            if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log("returned: %o", a.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                alert($A.util.json.encode(a.getError()));
            }
        })

        $A.enqueueAction(createLeads);
    }
})
```

Comment: are there any ETA when this issue will be fixed? And will it be fixed at all ?

Comment: Doug, this is ridiculous, 2 years now and it still doesn't work? `System.debug(items.getSobjectType()); // null, lol` when `items` is a `List<Contact>`. It seems everything is OK with single records, it's "just" the collection that's broken because my upsert complains at it: "System.TypeException: DML on generic List<SObject> only allowed for insert, update or delete"

Comment: Seriously this is ridiculous. Still it is not fixed. I'm trying to pass list of wrapper to apex and getting "Internal Salesforce.com Error" :(
The workaround suggested to pass string is not sufficient as string too has limit of 600000 chars.

Answer (score 4):

This should work (both scenarios)- I'm looking into what the underlying error is. I suspect this is specific to how our json deserializer is wired to Apex. You should not have to drop to serializing to strings manually.

Comment: any update on this issue? I am running into similar internal server errors when passing Apex wrapper classes as parameters on Spring '16. While passing a JSON string is fine for our internal dev team, these methods are going to be exposed as part of a managed package so asking someone else to give us a correctly formatted string is really not ideal.

Comment: This is a very big deal for our development because we were planning on making a component that has checkboxes, to overcome the problem that Related Lists in lightning do not have checkboxes.  Now our component is generating this same internal server error.

Comment: Still happening folks. Pretty basic functionality to not be working.

Comment: Any update on this? This is a huge blocker for us at the moment.

Comment: Same here...any updates on this?

Comment: I'm also still running into this issue. Any timeline on a fix?

Comment: Are lists broken in general? Please see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218511/does-auraenabled-serialization-of-listmapstring-object-work.