# Salesforce lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is it possible to pass a list or Set to apex class function (@AuraEnabled) from lightning component.
I am getting Error Message "Internal Server Error"

```
//Initialize the Apex Controller Method to be called
var saveAction = component.get("c.testfunction");
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];

//Pass the parameters to the Apex controller method
saveAction.setParams ({
    "pListfruits": fruits
});

saveAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
   alert('@@ response @@ ' + saveAction.getError()[0].message);
});
$A.enqueueAction(saveAction);

Apex Function:
@AuraEnabled
public static void testfunction(list<String> lstfruits) {
    System.debug('@@ lstfruits@@' + lstfruits);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55464/sobject-array-parameter-in-lightning-causes-internal-salesforce-com-error-in-ape it's from last year but maybe still an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be running into issues with the differences between a Javascript List/Array and a Apex/Java List. The lightning error messages are extremely unhelpful, so you may want to try a different approach entirely. One approach that I have used consistently (and reliably) is to pass data as a JSON string. so you would do something like this:

```
//Initialize the Apex Controller Method to be called
var saveAction = component.get("c.testfunction");
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];

//Pass the parameters to the Apex controller method
saveAction.setParams ({
    "pListfruits": JSON.stringify(fruits)
});

saveAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
   alert('@@ response @@ ' + saveAction.getError()[0].message);
});
$A.enqueueAction(saveAction);

Apex Function:
@AuraEnabled
public static void testfunction(String lstfruits) {
    Map<String, Object> jsonObj = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(lstfruits);
    //then do stuff with the map...
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped